# (Vectors) Split vector into multiple vectors with constant magnitude

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For start, this question definitely has anwser, but I don't seem to find one, of even find starting point.

Anyway, this "algorithm" is used in robot arm controling, which I'm also doing.

Here's the problem:
We have vectors V1 and V2, which have constant magnitue(picture them as solid cast iron).
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4MtF.png)

Now, new point comes. I need to move tip point of arm to the new point.
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GLiI.png)

How do I find out angles of before aformentioned vectors(V1 and V2) to get to the new point?(magnitute of vectors can't change)

My gut is also telling me that there are two solutions for each signle vector(from left and from right). I would also apreciate if someone can anwser how would I get right and left side respectivly.
Also one bonus question, how do I do this with more vectors in system(3, 4, n...). Can same system also be applied in 3D space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the coordinate of a point $A$ are $(x,y)$, and the length of the two sections of the arm are $v_1$ and $v_2$. You can access any point in a ring with inner radius $|v_1-v_2|$ and outer radius $v_1+v_2$ ($v_1$, $v_2$, and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ form the sides of a triangle). You can use now law of cosines to get the angles of the triangle. So, for example, the angle between $r$ and $v_1$ is given by $$\cos\theta=\frac{v_1^2+r^2-v_2^2}{2v_1r}$$
You know the angle that $r$ is doing with the horizontal (from $x$ and $y$). Now you can add or subtract $\theta$ to get the position of the first arm. You can then continue with the second arm.

For the case of multiple segments, the solution is not unique. I can keep the end of the robotic arm fixed while moving the joints. Similarly for 3D, even with two segments, one can keep the end of the arm fixed and rotate the joint around $\vec r$

Answer (score 0):

Let the angle which $\vec{v_1}$ makes with the $x$-axis be called $\theta$. Then the coordinates of its ‘tip’ will be $(v_1 \cos \theta, \,v_1 \sin \theta)$. Now, given the point you want to reach( let’s say it is $(a,b)$ ), you can use the distance formula to calculate $\theta$:

$$v_2 = \sqrt{ (v_1 \cos \theta -a)^2 + (v_1 \sin \theta - b)^2}$$

You can use a similar approach for the *left* solution.